# How to filter a list without using $scope.$watch()?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter some array in my Angular templates, but am getting errors saying `10 $digest cycles have been been reached`, so Angular aborts. After some searching, this is because `filterFilter` returns a new array every time, so Angular thinks the array is changing.

```
<tbody ng-if="!model.isLoading">
                <tr ng-repeat="user in filter(model.Users.dataSet, {'cTemplateId':model.UI.selectedTemplate.id}) track by user.id">
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.emailAddress}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr sk-no-result="filter(model.Users.dataSet, {'cTemplateId':model.UI.selectedTemplate.id})" label="No users found"></tr>
            </tbody>
```

This has forced me to use $watches on the controller like this:

```
$scope.$watch('model.UI.selectedTemplate', function(newVal){
        $scope.model.Users.filtered = filterFilter($scope.model.Users.dataSet, {'cTemplateId': $scope.model.UI.selectedTemplate.id});
    });
```

But I don't like this because there are other times when the list will have to be updated (eg changing pagination) and I don't want to create $watches for each one of these events.

Is there a way to run the filtering in the HTML templates so it gets updated all the time?

Comment: yes the problematic code is the `<tr>` where I use `filterFilter(model.Users.dataset, ...` in the template. What else would you like?

Comment: it is the built in AngularJS filter.. I mean I guess I could find their code but why is that needed?

Comment: `filterFilter` is the built in AngularJS filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do your `user` looks like when filtered? `ng-repeat` need to keep the array elements according to a `tracking` function.

By default its tracks the whole object (*via* their $$hashkey property), which means that if `filterFilter(...)` return new objects everytime it is read (even if the objects *look* the same), Angular will not be able to stabilize its digest cycle.

One way to prevent that would be to make sure that a same call to `filterFilter` would return the *same* array (same pointers), with some caching mechanism.

But there is an easier solution, which is tracking a specific property instead of the whole object for every item in your array. For instance if every `user` has a unique `id` (the tracked property has to be unique), you could simply use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in filterFilter(...) track by user.id)">
```

In some cases, when the array is ordered and the same user will always be in the same place, you can simply track by their index in the array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in filterFilter(...) track by $index)">
```

On the next digect cycle, angular will check if the tracked property for a given item in the array has changed or not, which is most of the time also more performant than tracking a whole object.

Comment: so I tried that and it seems to work ok when I only have this in the template in 1 place, however I use the same `fiterFilter` in another directive for displaying a row when no results exist. When I try to use them both, it gives me the same errors

Comment: I just updated my question to show the entire element. As you can see I need to have the filtering in more than 1 place. Doing so gives me these digest errors

Comment: @MattHintzke Your error comes from the ng-repeat or the second directive? Also, if you manually filter your users and look at the result array, do you have any users with the same `id` or they are indeed unique?

Comment: Not sure, the error stack does not show any code, its just spewing out all of my data in the array. yes, all users have unique ids

Comment: try to comment out one and then the other and see which one, or both, throw the error

Comment: Oh, it is only in the second in my own directive... I bet it is because I am doing a watch in that directive to check if the length of the array is 0.

Comment: Yup... that was the problem.  My skNoResults directive typically takes an array and just checks to see if it's length > 0. That $watch inside the directives probably caused the problem

Comment: Good that you sort it out! Note that instead of a custom directive, for better readability by other devs you should just use `ng-show="array.length"` (or `ng-if` if you want to completely remove the element from the DOM instead of just hidding it)

Answer (score 0):

Do the objects in your array have an ID or some other unique identifier?

If so, I think you can fix this by adding "track by user.id" (or whatever your unique identifier is) to your html.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in filterFilter(model.Users.dataSet, {'cTemplateId': model.UI.selectedTemplate.id}) track by user.id">
```